# Meaning of statement that 'getcwd functions work correctly' in FreeBSD man page for mount_nullfs?

Tags: mount, freebsd, stat, bind-mount, cwd

In FreeBSD, [`man mount_nullfs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_nullfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) states that:

> The primary differences between a virtual copy of the file system and a
>       symbolic link are that **the [`getcwd(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getcwd&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) functions work correctly** in the virtual 
>       copy, and that other file systems may be mounted on the virtual copy
>       without affecting the original. A different device number for the virtual 
>       copy is returned by [`stat(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports), but in other respects it is indistinguishable 
>       from the original.

What is the full meaning/implication of this paragraph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The primary differences between a virtual copy of the file  system and a
>   symbolic link are that **the `getcwd(3)` functions work correctly** in the virtual 
>   copy,

`getcwd`’s behaviour with symlinked directories is a fairly well-known gotcha, documented in *Advanced Unix Programming* for example (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42816161/4500798) for a quote): `chdir` and `getcwd` aren’t symmetric when symlinks are involved. One might expect that changing directories, using [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html), to a given directory, and then retrieving the current directory, using [`getcwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html), would return the same value; but that’s not the case when a process changes directory using a path containing a symbolic link — `getcwd` returns the path obtained after de-referencing all symbolic link(s). This can have unexpected consequences when changing directories to a parent directory, when the path containing symbolic link(s) and the de-referenced path have different numbers of components.

> and that other file systems may be mounted on the virtual copy
>   without affecting the original.

Continuing Stéphane’s [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426617/86440), you can mount another file system on a sub-directory of `/tmp/b` without affecting `/some/dir`, whereas mounting a file system on a sub-directory of `/tmp/a` will make it show up under `/some/dir` too.

> A different device number for the virtual 
>   copy is returned by `stat(2)`, but in other respects it is indistinguishable 
>   from the original.

This means that running `stat` on the copy, or any file thereunder, will return a different device number compared to the original, but that’s the only difference; apart from that, `stat("/tmp/b/c", &buf)` and `stat("/some/dir/c", &buf)` would return the same information.

Comment: Thanks - however the link you gave for "gotcha" isn't much help, as the users problem was mis-parsing English. Could you elaborate/expand your first para, to clarify in more detail? Thanks

Comment: I was using the SO question as a reference for the AUP quote, rather than because it was useful in and of itself. I’ve expanded the explanation, hopefully it’s clearer now...

Answer (score 4):

I think they mean that if `/tmp/a` is a symlink to `/some/dir` and `/tmp/b` is a nullfs mount of `/some/dir`,

- after `chdir("/tmp/a")`, `getcwd()` returns `/some/dir`.
- after `chdir("/tmp/b")`, `getcwd()` returns `/tmp/b`.

It's not that much that the former is *incorrect*. It's just that symlinks and nullfs mounts have two different semantics.

A symlink is a pointer to another file which most system calls (including `chdir()`) follow, while a nullfs mount makes a whole directory tree available under a different path (and contrary to Linux' similar bind-mounting feature or directory hard links in some other systems, the files there appear as being different files).

The symlink handling can break some people expectations (like that `getcwd()` here), but nullfs mounts (or the bindfs fuse filesystem on Linux or some union filesystems) can break other people expectations like the fact `[ /tmp/b/x -ef /some/dir/x ]` would return false even though they are the same file underneath, or that `fuser /tmp/b/x` could return nothing even when there are processes that have it opened via the `/some/dir/x` path.

The Linux bind-mounts (which do not make the files appear as being different) could break some other people expectations, like `find -xdev`/`du -x` traversing the mount point, two links to the same file with a link-count of 1 (it also allows loops to be created in the filesystem; FreeBSD's nullfs guards against that).

Hard links (the oldest of those technologies that make files appear under different paths) as well can break some users expectations (like that when you unlink a file from a directory, you expect it to no longer be available).

So I wouldn't say that one is more *correct* than the other here.

Comment: There's no such thing as a *bind* `nmount()` in FreeBSD.  A mount of a nullfs is just a mount.

Comment: @JdeBP, by _bind mount_ I meant the nature of those directories bound to another one. That's a terminology familiar to Linux users as that's the name of the (a similar) API there. I've changed that to _nullfs mount_, but that makes it less clear what I mean. Please let me know if you know a better wording familiar to FreeBSD folks.

Comment: Actually, it makes it more clear.  Answering with Linux jargon inapplicable to the operating system makes it less clear.  As far as I am aware, the FreeBSD terminology is indeed nullfs, or `mount_nullfs`, mount.  That's what the _Handbook_ and various other pieces of doco use, at any rate.